# DynamicPopulateExtender ,TextArea and line feeds

Tags: web-services, soap

I have this in a page :

```
<textarea id="taEditableContent" runat="server" rows="5"></textarea>
<ajaxToolkit:DynamicPopulateExtender ID="dpeEditPopulate" runat="server" TargetControlID="taEditableContent"
        ClearContentsDuringUpdate="true" PopulateTriggerControlID="hLink" ServicePath="/Content.asmx"
        ServiceMethod="EditContent" ContextKey='<%=ContextKey %>' />
```

Basically, a DynamicPopulateExtender that fills the contents of a textarea from a webservice. Problem is, no matter how I return the line breaks, the text in the text area will have no line feeds.

If I return the newlines as "br/" the entire text area remains empty. If I return new lines as "/r/n" , I get all the text as one continous line.  The webservice returns the string correctly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://rprealm.com/">First line


Third line
Fourth line</string>
```

But what I get in the text area is :

```
First line Third line Fourth line
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the white space is ignored by default when the XML is processed. Try to add the `xml:space="preserve"` attribute to the string element. You'll also need to define the xml prefix as `xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following style on textarea: **style="white-space: pre"**